# How to save JSON encoded array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble saving this array to MySQL.

```
$arr = array("red","green","blue");

json_encode($arr);

$results = $db->query("UPDATE settings SET data='$arr' WHERE type='testing'");
```

The database field is updated and just shows "Array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass it into variable as. Yours not working because you have encoded the array but didn't passed the encoded value

```
$arr = json_encode($arr);

$results = $db->query("UPDATE settings SET data='$arr' WHERE type='testing'");
```

Comment: You are using a wrong name as variabele and thus you suggest that $arr is an array which is not the fact. You should change that to a name like $json.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have discarded the value of `json_encode()`, save that by changing this line `json_encode($arr);` to

```
$arr = json_encode($arr);
```

---

Or, if you want to preserve your `$arr` for future use, change your query like,

```
$results = $db->query("UPDATE settings SET data='{json_encode($arr)}' WHERE type='testing'");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the description of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can see the sentence:

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

So you have to fetch the result and save them first in a variable. You can use the same and overwrite them something like this:

```
$arr = array("red","green","blue");
$arr = json_encode($arr);
$results = $db->query("UPDATE settings SET data='$arr' WHERE type='testing'");
```

Then it should work.